# Using Scrapy to get itune podcast data

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to get itune podcast data, however I am having trouble scraping podcast data from itune RSS feed using response.xpath in Scrapy.

I have tried using requests, which works fine

```
import requests

url='https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=200/genre=1302/explicit=true/json'

r=requests.get(url)
data=r.json()['feed']['entry']

podcast_url=[data[i]['link']['attributes']['href'] for i in range(len(data)) ]
title=[data[i]['im:name']['label'] for i in range(len(data)) ]
podcast_url=[data[i]['link']['attributes']['href'] for i in range(len(data)) ]
name=[data[i]['im:name']['label'] for i in range(len(data)) ]
artist=[data[i]['im:artist']['label'] for i in range(len(data)) ]
category=[data[i]['category']['attributes']['term'] for i in range(len(data)) ]
release_date=[data[i]['im:releaseDate']['label'] for i in range(len(data)) ]
```

However, I need to incorporate that into a Scrapy Crawler to get podcast rating from each individual podcast url. I don't know how to use scrapy to scrape JSON responses, so instead I tried the xml.

```
scrapy shell https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=200/genre=1302/explicit=true/xml -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; IntelMac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36'

response.xpath('//feed/entry/title/text()').extract()
```

I tried the above code in scrapy shell and got blank response. The response status was 200 and I was able to see content using `view(response)`

Basically, I am trying to write 'Step 2' in this spider:

```
import scrapy

categories=[1301, 1303, 1304, 1305, 1307, 1309, 1310, 1311, 1314, 1315,1316, 1318, 1321, 1323, 1324, 1325]
start_urls=['https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=200/genre=' + str(category) + '/explicit=true/xml' for category in categories]


class ImgtSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "podcast"

    #step 1 get json from RSS feed
    def start_requests(self):

        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_podcast)

    #step 2 extract podcast title, artist,category,release_date and podcast_url       
    def parse_podcast(self, response):



        for podcast_url in podcast_urls:
           yield scrapy.Request(url=podcast_url,callback=self.parse_rating)

    #step 3 extract podcast rating from podcast_url
    def parse_rating(self, response):

        rating = response.css('figcaption.we-rating-count.star-rating__count::text').extract_first()
        request_url=response.request.url

        yield {"rating": rating,
               "url": request_url}
```

Comment: “I don't know how to use scrapy to scrape JSON responses”. `json.loads(response.text)`.

Comment: Regarding XPath, you are probably a victim of https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom